# Can I get the nice visuals of R-Markdown plotting using non-markdown R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am trying to get my ggplots to look as nice as possible. When using R Markdown, the plot comes out with extremely smooth lines:

[image]

However, when using standard R (still in RStudio, if that matters), the same plot comes out like this:

[image]

(It may not look that bad here, but the wobbly lines can often get very choppy in practice.)

I have tried to include an MWE for the plot, I'm not sure if I need to include anything about my R-Markdown settings. Nothing crazy, they are pretty fundamental.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, dplyr, ggplot2)

x <- 0:10
demand <- function(x) 10 - x
supply <- function(x) 1 + x
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0:10)), aes(x)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10.5), expand = c(0, 0), breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10.5), expand = c(0, 0), breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Q", y = "P") +
  stat_function(aes(x), fun = supply, size = 1) + # supply function
  stat_function(aes(x), fun = demand, size = 1)
```

I don't want to use R-Markdown every time I produce a plot, for reasons I don't want to go into. Is there some way to get the nice visual output in regular R?

Much thanks in advance, extra thanks for politeness.

Comment: What file format are you using to save your plots? PDF or PNG or something else? Are you using RMarkdown to generate PDFs? Or what type of output are you generating?

Comment: In non-markdown, I am using png, not pdf. The output of the RMarkdown is html at the moment, only because I am having trouble rendering pdfs with markdown

Comment: Update: I was able to render a pdf in r markdown, and the graph still has perfect lines

Comment: Ah, it seems that just saving as a pdf rather than a png in normal R helps? I feel dumb for not trying that. I guess the pdf is just a nicer output?

Comment: PDF is vector graphics, PNG is pixels. You can also increase the resolution of your PNG to make it nicer. `ggsave` defaults to 300 dpi, which is usually plenty, but if you show your code for saving the plot maybe we can give you pointers. You can also install and use the `cairoDevice` package for PNGs using `type = "cairo"` in `ggsave()`. The Cairo PNG device often looks better than the built-in version.

Comment: Don't take away from this "always use PDF". PDF will look good, especially when you zoom in, but it also encodes all the graphic data in the file. If you save an image with 10s of thousands of points, overplotted with transparency, it can create a **very** big file. The same plot saved as a PNG with high resolution will be just about as good to look at with a tiny fraction of the file size.

Comment: You might also install the `ragg` package as use that as your default R device, to get better anti-aliasing on graphs and better font handling: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/modern-text-features/

Comment: Specifically, you can go to 'Tools > Global Options > Graphics tab > Backend' and select the AGG or Cairo devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it with `ggsave` to have a high-quality image. `ggsave` will save the last plot you ran. Here is an example:

```
ggsave("myplot.png", device = "png",
       width = 10, height = 4, units = "in", dpi = 600, type = "cairo-png")
```

It will still look funny when you see preview in RStudio, but the image will be saved with smooth lines. Here is the image I saved with the code above:

[image]

In `device`you can choose how you want to save the plot. From the function documentation:

> Device to use. Can either be a device function (e.g. png()), or one of "eps", "ps", "tex" (pictex), "pdf", "jpeg", "tiff", "png", "bmp", "svg" or "wmf" (windows only).